# Why python does not recognize shell assignments with ! syntax

Tags: python, shell

Python, python2 or python3, regardless of which one I use, a simple shall command (e.g. cat, head) does not work.

```
>>> !cat testhts.txt
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    !cat testhts.txt
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Probably I am missing something very simple but I have spent too much time to keep looking by myself. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what makes you think this would work?

Comment: This only works in iPython (jupyter) kernel.

Comment: Why would python recognize shell assignments with ! syntax? (or any shell syntax/command for that matter)

Comment: "Probably I am missing something very simple" => well yes indeed: the fact that the Python shell only executes Python code.

Comment: `!`-prefixed commands are a feature of iPython/jupyter, not the Python language.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute shell code in python you can use the subprocess module.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(' '.join(['cat','testhts.txt']),shell=True)
```

As mentioned by Josef, using ! only works in jupyter notebooks.